# "XnDeviceSensorV2' failed" on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, raspbian, openni, asus-xtion

I am new on connecting and using an Xtion Pro Live camera through Raspberry Pi (OS: raspbian wheezy). The camera is connected properly to the raspberry pi.

I followed the steps from  http://mewgen.com/Ge107_files/20120921%20Setting%20up%20Rasberry%20pi%20for%20the%20Xtion%20and%20kinect.html
 in order to operate the Xtion(openni and sensors).

When i try to run the command (as root) 
"cd /unstable/SensorKinect/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/
./RedistMaker Arm" 
i get this error:

../Common/CommonCppMakefile:118: recipe for target 'Arm-Release/XnSensorDepthGenerator.o' failed
make: [Arm-Release/XnSensorDepthGenerator.o] Error 
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/unstable/SensorKinect/Platform/Linux/Build/XnDeviceSensorV2'
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'XnDeviceSensorV2' failed
make:  [XnDeviceSensorV2] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/unstable/SensorKinect/Platform/Linux/Build'

I have done all the changes that the author of the above site suggests, but the problem remains.

Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: You'll have to dig through the Makefiles or any log files that build system might produce, find the actual command that fails and gives a sensible error message, otherwise we can just guess as to what's going wrong as much as you can.

Comment: Could you give me a little help about where to find those Makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downloading the SensorKinect-unstable.zip from https://github.com/ph4m/SensorKinect/archive/unstable.zip

Then i followed these instructions:

unzip the file

cd SensorKinect/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/

chmod +x RedistMaker

./RedistMaker

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using Maria's link: https://github.com/ph4m/SensorKinect/archive/unstable.zip

I had to edit this file:

```
./Platform/Linux/Build/Common/Platform.Arm
and delete  ‘-mfloat-abi=softfp‘.
```

After that, execute: `chmod +x RedistMaker`

```
./RedistMaker
```